# MySQLi Query Joining using 1 table

Tags: mysql, join

I am struggling to understand how to query 1 table (locations) and join (left, right or inner) not sure.

Table: locations
Fields: locationID, locationParentID, locationName

locationID | locationParentID | locationName

1          | 0                | Northern Ireland
2          | 0                | United Kingdom
3          | 0                | Scotland
4          | 1                | County Down
5          | 1                | County Armagh
6          | 2                | London
7          | 2                | Leeds
8          | 3                | Glasgow
9          | 3                | Edinburgh
10         | 4                | Belfast
11         | 4                | Newtownards

Can anyone please point me in the right direction so that I can perform 1 query with some kind of join for this 3 level location structure on 1 table?

```
SELECT * FROM locations (JOIN EACH SUB LOCATION AS ['sub'] WHICH MATCHES LOCATION_PARENT_ID) ORDER BY locationParentID,locationName ASC.




SELECT * FROM _locations 
JOIN _locations as parent_location 
ON _locations.locationParentID = parent_location.locationID
JOIN _locations AS super_parent_location 
ON parent_location.locationParentID = super_parent_location.locationID


Array
(
[0] => 117
[locationID] => 1
[1] => 19
[locationParentID] => 0
[2] => Hull
[locationName] => England
[3] => hull
[locationUri] => 
[4] => 2
[locationLevel] => 1
[5] => 19
[6] => 1
[7] => East Yorkshire
[8] => 
[9] => 2
[10] => 1
[11] => 0
[12] => England
[13] => 
[14] => 1
)
```

I would like to try and get

```
Array
(
[locationID] => 1
[locationParentID] => 0
[locationName] => England
[locationUri] => 
[locationLevel] => 1
[sub'] => Array (
                [locationID] => 55
                [locationParentID] => 1
                [locationName] => Leeds
                [locationUri] => 
                [locationLevel] => 2
                [sub'] => Array (
                                [locationID] => 144
                                [locationParentID] => 55
                                [locationName] => Chorley
                                [locationUri] => 
                                [locationLevel] => 3))
)
```

Really desperate to get this working now, if anyone could please provide any further sugestions I would be very grateful.

my current query is

```
SELECT * FROM _locations 
JOIN _locations as parent_location 
ON _locations.locationParentID = parent_location.locationID
JOIN _locations AS super_parent_location 
ON parent_location.locationParentID = super_parent_location.locationID
```

which outputs all the fields but I would like to have returned a 3 level deep array using mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQL_ASSOC);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM location 
JOIN location as parent_location 
  ON location.locationParentID = parent_location.locationID
JOIN location AS super_parent_location 
  ON parent_location.locationParentID = super_parent_location.locationID
```

Basically you just JOIN to the same table over and over and use aliases.